# Get coordinates from Tweet | Search api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing an application to search tweets by a hashtag and get tweet coordinates and put it on google maps. The result I am getting contains empty geo field. I searched alot on Stackoverflow and Twitter community about this but getting empty geo & coordinates for all tweets. Even though I tweet with my location open but still getting empty fields.

```
...
    public 'geo' => null
    public 'coordinates' => null
    public 'place' => null
    public 'contributors' => null
    public 'is_quote_status' => boolean false
    public 'retweet_count' => int 0
    public 'favorite_count' => int 0
    public 'entities' =>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using? Twitter's search API does return geotagged tweets.

Comment: Twitter api returns geo details if tweet has that data;